# Using vi how to obtain a number of time a word or pattern occur in the file

Tags: vim, vi

How do calculate the number from inside the vim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For counting the number of times some pattern occurs, use:

```
:%s/pattern//gn
```

Comment: +1 see :help count-items :  
An alternative is using |v_g_CTRL-G| in Visual mode.

Comment: I generally still use & for the replacement (`:%s/pattern/&/gn`); this way if you forget the "n", you still don't affect your file (yes, I know you can just undo it).

Answer (score 2):

The following will work with unmodifiable files, and the result can be kept and used elsewhere in our scripts.

```
:let g:n = 0
:g/pattern/let g:n += 1
:echo g:n
```